# Animating sail attached to ropes

Tags: modeling, animation, cloth-simulation

I am modeling a viking longboat [similar to this one](https://www.flickr.com/photos/infomatique/1116654237). I would like to use blenders' cloth simulation to accurately model the deformation of the sail such as the bottom two corners of the square are attached to ropes.

So far I have that :

[image]

(the red circles indicate the vertex group used to pin the sail). It consists of a square plane with the top row and the two bottom vertices in a pin group. The sail has a cloth modifier and a wind force field deforms the shape ([same as the accepted answer in this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75952/create-a-sail-with-cloth-and-curves-acting-as-softbodies)).

Which approach should I take to add ropes on each side at the bottom of the sail and achieve a more realistic deformation such as [this one](https://www.flickr.com/photos/infomatique/1116670727) ?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75952/create-a-sail-with-cloth-and-curves-acting-as-softbodies

Comment: Thanks for the link, I already saw it (the result I got on the screenshot above actually use that technique) but it doesn't work in my case : I want accurate deformation of the sail